# EOF when using raw_input in sublime text 2 inside the code of a program, not in the console

Tags: python, sublimetext2, raw-input, sublimerepl

I've found other people asking about a similar issue, but everything seems to only be a way to get raw_input to work in the console that sublimerepl enables inside sublime text. Using raw_input outside of the console (inside a file) still seems impossible. Is there any way to get around this, and if there isn't how would I get a raw_input equivalent.

Comment: Use a better IDE. All dups of this question on SO are suggesting REPL, seems like it's the only way out.

Comment: I used repl, and it fixed the issue inside the sublime text python console. The issue is that it doesn't fix the issue inside saved files of python code, which seems strange as it can clearly solve the issue for some cases.